# How to use Identity Server 4 Sign-in with desktop/mobile apps

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a .Net Core Identity Server, a .Net Core Api, our clients however are desktop and mobile apps.

Looking through the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin.html#sign-in) it seems our Users need to Sign-in using Hybrid flow, however it seems this flow is for Web browser apps.

What is the correct flow/grant_type to Authenticate my Desktop Users and give them access to the Api?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hybrid flow is correct. See this spec:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-09

You can use this library:
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2

and here are some sample:
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples

Comment: Thanks but browsers will not be enabled on my users machines, the draft and the Oidc client seem to use the browser still.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use 'Resource Owner Password' grant type?

Comment: You can - but you might be missing out on a couple of features https://vimeo.com/171942749

Comment: Yes I was considering using Resource Owner Password, but the video is priceless, this opened my eyes, we will indeed look at embedding an open source browser into our Clients (eg Chromium), Many thanks

Comment: Using your NetCoreConsoleClient, im trying to use my own ID4 server and Api, what Grant_type do I use for the client?

Comment: It would be nice to see your Config (clients users etc..) for your ID4 demo server Thanks

Comment: The video by @leastprivilege is no longer available by that URL. It was moved to https://vimeo.com/channels/1213843/171942749 (or google "Authentication & secure API access for native & mobile Applications - Dominick Baier")

Comment: is there a way to still use ID4 for sign-in but not requiring a web browser to load the sign-in page? my mobile app users are having a hard time waiting for the web browser to load properly.

Comment: @pau_learnstocode did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue at the moment